Formalizing an infinite sum
The harmonic series ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$) diverges. let a $\in Re$.
For all a, the sum $\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. However, what if you want to ask something like...
$\lim_{a \to \infty}  \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{n}$
How would you start to formalize this question?

Some thoughts...

Consider a grid which shows the sum assuming different values of x and k
x $\rightarrow\space\space\space1\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space3\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space4\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space5 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space. . . $
k
$\downarrow\space$
$1$ $\space\space\space\space\space \sum_{n=1}^1\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\sum_{n=1}^1\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2} \space\space\space...\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\sum_{n=1}^1\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{5}\space\space...  approaches \space 0 \space as \space x \rightarrow \infty $
$2$ $\space\space\space\space\space \sum_{n=1}^2\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \space\space\sum_{n=1}^2\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2} \space\space\space\space...\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\sum_{n=1}^2\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{5}\space\space...  approaches \space 0 \space as \space x \rightarrow \infty $
$3$ $\space\space\space\space\space\space...$
$4$ $\space\space\space\space\space\sum_{n=1}^4\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1}\space\space...$
$...\space\space\space div \space as\space k\rightarrow\infty \space \space \space \space \space \space div \space as\space k\rightarrow\infty \space\space...$
It appears that if you first let x approach infinity, then take the sum with increasingly large values of k, you could argue that the sum converges - especially because the sum of the k-1th sum (assuming x has already approached infinity) is 0. However, if you first let k approach infinity, then take increasingly large values of x, it appears that the sum would diverge.
Maybe this is an issue because I am not formulating this limit correctly - I don't know how to deal with infinity. Any help appreciated.

$\lim_{a\to\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n,a)$ is the shorthand for $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n,a)\right),$$ so this becomes, in your case, $$\lim_{a\to\infty}+\infty=\infty.$$

If you swap rhe two limits, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{a\to\infty},$ the limit is $0.$

You can also define $\lim_{(n,a)\to(\infty,\infty)},$ but in that case, the limit doesn't converge at all - taking different "paths" to  $(\infty,\infty)$ gives different limits.
